# script tag not activating on jquery load

Tags: jquery, tags, load

My problem is when I load a page into a div using jquery, the script tags don't active the way I wish (although they do activate from what I can tell).

I've seen a few different ways (such as $.getScript();) to load a script. However, no matter what I try, I cannot get the effect to work the same way as if I actually placed the code there instead of loading it in.

As such, I guess my question is how I should set something up to have about the same effect loading it in as the code really being there (as in activating in the same order it would normally).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you are going to like my answer, because its EVIL! but this is the only way I know to do this.

The reason your script tags are not activating is there is no event to attach it to. The scripts therefore cannot activate themselves. So here is the easiest way to make them run:

```
//find script tage in page html (your ajax call will return html, represented here as 'newPage'
var scriptAsStr = newPage.split('<script>')[1].split('</script>')[0];
// run that script with eval
eval(scriptAsStr);
```

Comment: looks promising, but no matter where I put it I get "')[0]; eval(scriptAsStr);" printed out, not sure why. Also, even with the html, doesn't jquery .load strip script tags? Although I could be misunderstanding where I should put this.

Comment: @Kyomu you are correct about .load stripping out script tags, I forgot about that. If you use `$.get` you should be fine. I pulled that code out of one of my own projects, so you may need to alter it to get what you need, but you get the idea. You need the contents of the script tag as a string, then you can `eval`.

Comment: For some reason is didn't like the /. So looking at the script, I believe I've found the problem. The script is attempting to document.write, and I think activating it in a different order than it wanted messed it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to have new elements inserted into a div respond to events like `click`, you should use the following in the the main header script:

```
$(document).on('click', "#mynewdiv", function() {----});
```

This will target the div with that id once it has been created inside of the document, which already exists on page load.

If you have a wrapper element that already exists and you want to target all inserted elements specific to that element, you can be more precise with:

```
 $("#wrapper").on('click', "*", function() {----});
```

Comment: I'm looking for how to make an external script element in a html file loaded into a div activate as it would (or at least similar) as when I actually place the code there. However, i never knew you could do .on, I have always done .live, learn something new all the time :)